# For each fc in range.formatconditions fails. Why?

Tags: vba, excel

The following code works for most sheets in my workbook:

```
Function IsHighlighted() As Boolean

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Dim rUsedRange As Range
        Set rUsedRange = wks.UsedRange

        With rUsedRange
            Dim bHighlighted As Boolean

            Dim fc As FormatCondition
            For Each fc In .FormatConditions
                If fc.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) And fc.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then
                    bHighlighted = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next fc

            If bHighlighted = True Then
                Exit For
            End If
        End With
        Debug.Print (wks.Name & "," & rUsedRange.FormatConditions.count)
    Next wks

    IsHighlighted = bHighlighted
End Function
```

But it fails on the line `For Each fc In .FormatConditions` with the error message type mismatch on a worksheet that has `rUsedRange.FormatConditions.Count = 34` out of which many are icon sets.

Why does the code fail on this sheet? How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you post your workbook for us to look at?

Comment: Sorry, no, it's a huge workbook with sensitive data

Comment: Redundant request given Rory's answer - good question btw.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `FormatConditions` collection includes `FormatCondition`, `DataBar`, `AboveAverage`, `ColorScale`, `UniqueValues`, `Top10` and `IconSetCondition` objects, not just `FormatCondition` objects, so you need to declare your `fc` variable as `Object`.

Comment: Ahha, great. The following if statement also seems to produce errors, I guess for formatconditions that do not have .interior.color and .font.color. Can you think of a nice way of handling these errors? Can/should I test that the fc is really a formatcondition before executing the if statement?

Comment: @user1283776 That should probably be a new question.

Comment: @user1283776 Yes, test it with `TypeName`.