# Ignore items in a formatconditions collection that are not formatcondition?

Tags: vba, excel

The following code works for most sheets in my workbook:

```
Function IsHighlighted() As Boolean

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Dim rUsedRange As Range
        Set rUsedRange = wks.UsedRange

        With rUsedRange
            Dim bHighlighted As Boolean

            Dim fc As Object
            For Each fc In .FormatConditions
                If fc.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) And fc.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then
                    bHighlighted = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next fc

            If bHighlighted = True Then
                Exit For
            End If
        End With
        Debug.Print (wks.Name & "," & rUsedRange.FormatConditions.count)
    Next wks

    IsHighlighted = bHighlighted
End Function
```

But some of my sheets contain icon sets.

Apparently:
The `FormatConditions` collection includes `FormatCondition`, `DataBar`, `AboveAverage`, `ColorScale`, `UniqueValues`, `Top10` and `IconSetCondition` objects, not just `FormatCondition` objects.
For more context, see: [For each fc in range.formatconditions fails. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28456730/for-each-fc-in-range-formatconditions-fails-why/28457706#28457706)

Some of these don't have `.Interior.Color` so the if statement throws an error.

What is a nice way I can skip all of these objects in the formatconditions collection that are not of the type formatcondition?

I tried using `VarType(fc)` to determine the obejct type, but it only retuns a 9 which says that `fc` is some kind of object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the Typename function, 
for example:

```
Dim str as string.
Msgbox Typename(str)  ' ->>> "String"
```

Comment: For some reason I didn't get it to work when I tried it before. But it works well

Comment: Happy to be of service.